# Error occured after installing plank in ubuntu

Tags: taskbar, plank

when I open an app, it's icon gets displayed twice on the taskbar. I want to hide anyone of them. The screenshot would explain my question:
[image: see this image]

Comment: Left is not Plank. It's Unity. The best use-case for Plank is to use it with MATE DE or Xfce.